# How to Limit Size of Radius With d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm sure the solution is straight forward, but I'm trying to find out how to limit the range of radius when I plot circles onto a geomap.  I have values that range in size significantly, and the larger values end up covering a significant amount of the map.

```
d3.csv("getdata.php", function(parsedRows) {

    data = parsedRows
    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      var mapCoords = this.xy([data[i].long, data[i].lat])
      data[i].lat = mapCoords[0]
      data[i].long = mapCoords[1]
    }

    vis.selectAll("circle")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("svg:circle")
    .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.lat })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.long })
    .attr("stroke-width", "none")
    .attr("fill", function() { return "rgb(255,148,0)" })
    .attr("fill-opacity", .4)
    .attr("r", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.count)})
  })
```

This is what I have right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll probably want to use d3 [`scales`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quantitative-Scales) by setting the `domain` (min/max input values) and the `range` (min/max output allowed values). To make this easy, don't hesitate to use `d3.min` and `d3.max` to setup the domain's values.

`d3.scale` will return a function that you can use when assigning the `r` attribute value. For example:

```
var scale = d3.scale.linear.domain([ inputMin, inputMax ]).range([ outputMin, outputMax ]);
vis.selectAll("circle")
  // etc...
  .attr( 'r', function(d) { return scale(d.count) });
```

Comment: Thank you.  I was able to establish min/max values by hard coding the values as below, but I would like to set a method to set my scale domain with d3.min/d3.max, but I can't get my code to access data.count.  Below is what I'm doing now                         `var outputMin = 2;
var outputMax = 40;
d3.csv // etc...                                     var scale = d3.scale.linear()
.domain([ 0, 10000 ])
.range([ outputMin, outputMax ]);
  vis.selectAll("circle")
//
  .attr("r", function(d) { return scale(d.count)})`